# I have an error 1064 after sync databases with mysql workbench

Tags: database

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `ingredients` , ADD COLUMN `secimage` VARCHAR(250) NU' at line 1

```
ALTER TABLE `newlankawebsaloon`.`product` 
  ADD COLUMN `information` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `sub_category_idsub_category` , 
  ADD COLUMN `directions` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `information` , 
  ADD COLUMN `ingredients` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `directions` , 
  ADD COLUMN `new_up` DOUBLE(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `ingredients` , 
  ADD COLUMN `secimage` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `new_up` , 
  ADD COLUMN `time_mill` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `secimage` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_user1` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_category1` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_system_status1`
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Answer (score 0):

`Double` does not accept length. So in your case it should only be

```
ALTER TABLE `newlankawebsaloon`.`product` 
  ADD COLUMN `information` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `sub_category_idsub_category` , 
  ADD COLUMN `directions` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `information` , 
  ADD COLUMN `ingredients` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `directions` , 
  ADD COLUMN `new_up` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `ingredients` , 
  ADD COLUMN `secimage` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `new_up` , 
  ADD COLUMN `time_mill` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `secimage` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_user1` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_category1` , 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_product_system_status1`
```